# Can I change service link structure (custom permalink) on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Can I change the link structure on wordpress? My link structure for services page is like;

[www.website.com/service/digital](http://www.website.com/service/digital)

Is there any way to change "service" or remove "service" in this structure?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203951/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type-post-urls - you can also change service to whatever you want. What is the preference? Remove or change? Is this a custom post type? Is this just a child page/parent slug?

Comment: I'm working on a child theme. I can translate "service" to my language I think this way is better. Thanks for the link im reading it atm.